# (deep learning, rnn , cnn) image image captinoing with keras

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have made image captioning tutorial, but it doesn't work. help me...

image captioning is a model that explained the image a person inputs.

I don't have GPU, so I have to make the same model in tutorial, 
and then, I will load weights in tutorial directory.

I copy a image captioning tutorial

here is tutorial training model code:

```py
image_model = Sequential([
    Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
    RepeatVector(max_len)
    ])

caption_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_len),
    LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
])  

final_model = Sequential([
    Merge([image_model, caption_model], mode='concat', concat_axis=1),
    Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False)),
    Dense(vocab_size),
    Activation('softmax')
    ])

final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(),         
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, it doesn't work, some people say that this code is designed with Sequential. So, I change them to Function API. But I don't know well how to change them.

here is my code:

```py
embedding_size = 300
vocab_size = 8256
max_len = 40

image_model = Sequential([
    Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
    RepeatVector(max_len)
  ])

caption_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_len),
    LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
])

image_in = Input(shape=(2048,))
caption_in = Input(shape=(max_len, vocab_size))
merged = concatenate([image_model(image_in), caption_model(caption_in)], 
       axis=0)
latent = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))(merged)
out = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(latent)
model = Model([image_in(image_in), caption_in(caption_in)], out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(),             
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I got an error :

```sh
ValueError: "input_length" is 40, but received input has shape (None, 40, 8256)
```

please help me... I have spent 2 weeks only for this....

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, your input to the embedding layer has the wrong shape:

```
caption_in = Input(shape=(max_len, vocab_size))
```

Try changing it to:

```
caption_in = Input(shape=(max_len,))
```

Comment: error code : ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 6 layers into a model with 4 layers.

Comment: this error happens when I load wegihts designed with the tutorial model. tutorial model is designed with 6 layers, but my model consists of 4 layers.

Comment: Full tutorial code : https://github.com/yashk2810/Image-Captioning/blob/master/Image%20Captioning%20InceptionV3.ipynb